# Does "A is dense in B" imply that over any nonzero interval in B, there are infinitely many members of A?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I think my thinking is that the rationals are dense in the reals, and over any nonzero real interval there are (countably?) infinite rationals. But I am not sure if the formulation in the question title is a fallacious generalization to any set dense in any other. I suspect I am carrying over other properties of the reals. If "A is dense in B implies that over any finite interval in B there are infinite members of A" is false, then can you think of a similar but correct generalization?

(Honestly I think I might be too rusty to even ask this question correctly; like, does "nonzero interval" even have any meaning unless you've also defined metrics on a set with various additional properties, etc., etc.)

Comment: It does.  Because if not, we can refine the interval until there are no more points left in the interval, and then we would get an interval with no points, contradicting the definition of dense.

Comment: If you mean the generalization to general topological space, then your claim is false. For instance consider $\{1,2\}$ endowed with discrete topology: i.e. open sets are $\emptyset, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{1,2\}$. Set $A$ is dense in $A$ (obviously) but for an open set $\{1\}$ there are only finitely many members of $A$ in it, namely $1$.

Comment: If we assume B is a subset of the reals interval makes sense.  If not we can assume interval is equivalent to a neighborhood (or closure of a neighborhood) with non-zero radius. (no significant difference.)  Then this is true (I think) if we assume the interval contains infinite members of B, which we do not have to assume.

Answer (score 1):

The following definition really helped clarify the concept of density for me.

If $A$ is dense in $B$, then for any $\epsilon$ ball you create centered at a member of $B$, it contains at least one member of $A$.

We can see this is equivalent to every point of $B$ being a cluster point of $A$ (and also a limit point!).

Answer (score 0):

Kind of.

It's possible that the interval only has a finite number of points $\{b_i\}$ of B in its interior.  If so then each of these points is also a point of A. And these could be the only points of A in the interval.

However if we assume that interval has an infinite number of elements of B in its interior.  Then, yes, there are an infinite number of elements of A in its interior.  Assume not.  Then one of these point of B, call it b, is not a point of A.  b is in the interior of the interval so there exists a neighborhood of b within the interval.  As A is dense, this neighborhood contains a point of A.  Call is $a_0$.  But the neighborhood of b of radius less than $d(b, a_0)$ also has a point of A that isn't $a_0$.  Call this $a_1$.  Inductively we can show the original neighborhood of b and an infinite number of points of A where $0 < d(b, a_{i+1}) < d(b, a_{i})$.